# Duplicating rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe in a similar format to the below;

```
Sites            Points        Value
ABC,DEF          2             10
GHI, JKL,MNO     4             15
```

I want to create new rows for each of the points, which I have been able to do with the following code (disclaimer: I found this code but can't find to reference);

```
def duplicate_rows(df, countcol):
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    for i in range(int(row[countcol])-1):
        df = df.append(row)

df.sort_index(inplace=True)
return df


df_dup = duplicate_rows(base_df,'Points')
```

This gives an output of

```
Sites          Points     Values
ABC, DEF       2          10
ABC, DEF       2          10
GHI, JKL, MNO  4          15
GHI, JKL, MNO  4          15
GHI, JKL, MNO  4          15
GHI, JKL, MNO  4          15
```

What I am trying to achieve is;

```
Sites          Points     Values
ABC            2          10
DEF            2          10
GHI            4          15
JKL            4          15
MNO            4          15
MNO            4          15
```

Any ideas on how this could be achieved?

Comment: Why do you have double `MNO`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split (explode) pandas dataframe string entry to separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows)

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, and if you works on pandas 0.25+:

```
(df.assign(Sites=df.Sites.str.split(',\s*'))
   .explode('Sites')
)
```

Output:

```
  Sites  Points  Value
0   ABC       2     10
0   DEF       2     10
1   GHI       4     15
1   JKL       4     15
1   MNO       4     15
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DataFrame.explode`,

```
df['Sites'] = df['Sites'].str.split(',')
df.explode('Sites').reset_index(drop = True)


    Sites   Points  Value
0   ABC     2       10
1   DEF     2       10
2   GHI     4       15
3   JKL     4       15
4   MNO     4       15
```